# Flutter web: Opening direct URL navigation working on local but not after deployment

Tags: flutter-web, flutter-routes, flutter-web-browser

Even though there exists one Question that is already opened I didnt understand the approaches, but first to the problem itself.

On my local machine my routing works fine.

But when I host it I have the problem that I can navigate to a domain: `http://www.example.com` but not to a domain `http://www.example.com/privacy-policy` by direct URL Navigation.

The approaches that were suggested looked like:

1. htaccess file:
   So basicly this approach suggested adding these lines to my htaccess:

> ```
> RewriteEngine on 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-d 
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}% !-f 
> RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
> ```

I did and my whole file then looked like this as well. But it didnt change a thing. So did I something wrong? Should I implement the htaccess somehow?

2. Adding to Firebase.json:
   The other suggestion was adding following code to my firebase.json file:

> ```
> "hosting": {
>   "rewrites": [ {
>     "source": "**",
>     "destination": "/index.html"
>    } ]
> }
> ```

My problem is that I dont have a firebase.json file, so what shall I do with this snippet? Is it only relevant when you use firebase hosting?

So I saw the both approaches but I didnt understand how to implement them. I get that the essential problem is trying to push the route on the same index.html file, but Im not understanding how to properly tackle the behaviour. Maybe I dont have the background knowledge to implement the solutions properly

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by flutter sdk only. Not caused by firebase or any other  hosting services. I have tried all the redirection setups in firebase.json file, but later found the issue on github.

Upgrade to Flutter stable 3.7.4 or higher solved the issue.

Read the change notes `https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Hotfixes-to-the-Stable-Channel#374-feb-21-2023`

See the [issue](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/issues/2673) on github

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Not worked for me yet